# Alternating Odd Even or Even Odd in C#

Tags: c#, while-loop, do-while

I've created a program that adds all input values from the user and prints the sum if the user entered 0 or greater than 101. Here's my code:

```
int n, sum = 0;
do
{
    Console.Write("Enter a number:");
    n = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
    sum += n;
 }
 while (n != 0 && n < 101);
 Console.WriteLine("Sum is:" + sum);
 Console.ReadKey();
```

I'm trying to figure how to accepts numbers alternately. For example, Input values are: 4, 7, 8, 3, 6, 1. If the user input two consecutive odd or even number the system will not accept two consecutive odd or even or it will display the sum of all inputted numbers.

Comment: If you save the previous input value you could check if `(previousValue % 2) == (currentValue % 2)`.

Comment: You can store all user inputs in a [List<int>](https://www.tutorialsteacher.com/csharp/csharp-list) and you can do any kind of logic based on the already received inputs.

Answer (score 0):

Taking the recomendation of Andrew an Peter you can add the list to save your previous inputs and do some checks to the current and prev data to do the logic.

the code that implements this is the following:

```
        //save input list
        List<int> inputNumbers = new List<int>();
       
        int n, sum = 0;
        do
        {
            Console.Write("Enter a number:");
            n = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            //My Recomendation ==============================
                
                //save previus input numbers
                inputNumbers.Add(n);

                //Check is there are previous input number
                if(inputNumbers.Count>1){
                    //New control vars
                    Boolean previousNumberIsOdd= false,currentNumberIsOdd= false;

                    foreach (int item in inputNumbers)
                    {
                        Console.Write(item+",");
                    }
                    
                    //check if previus number is odd
                    if((inputNumbers[inputNumbers.Count-2])%2 == 0){
                        previousNumberIsOdd = true;
                    }

                    //Check if current number is odd
                    if(n%2==0){
                        currentNumberIsOdd = true;
                    }

                    Console.WriteLine("Control vars:" + previousNumberIsOdd +"/"+currentNumberIsOdd);
                    //Check diferent scenarios and do the logic
                    //previous and current number are odds
                    if(previousNumberIsOdd && currentNumberIsOdd){
                        
                        //break while and write the result
                        break;
                    }
                    //previous and current number are evens
                    if(!previousNumberIsOdd && !currentNumberIsOdd){
                        
                        //break while and write the result
                        break;
                    }
                }

            //if there aren't numbers to break the cycle then do the original logic 
            
            //End of my recomendation =====================
            
            sum += n;

        }
        while (n != 0 && n < 101);
        Console.WriteLine("Sum is:" + sum);
        Console.ReadKey();
        }
```

You can do many optimizations to this code but a put it like that to be very clear in the logic.

Answer (score 0):

By using two flag you can achieve the result.

```
int n, sum = 0;
bool previous = false, current;
bool init = true;

do
{
    Console.Write("Enter a number:");
    n = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
    current = n % 2 == 0;
    
    if( current == previous && !init)
        break;

    previous = current;
    init = false;
    sum += n;
 }
 while (n != 0 && n < 101);
 Console.WriteLine("Sum is:" + sum);
 Console.ReadKey();
```

Output

[image]